# ThreeFragment should reload 1 times to show the RecyclerView,Asynchronus task

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have `ViewPager` `TabLayout` which hosts 3 `Fragments`. Each Fragment contain `ListView` and data from `Firebase`. FragmentOne and FragmentTwo running with no problem,The problem isin FragmentThree raises blank screen. But after i reload FragmentThree 1 times like on this video the data and RecyclerView just appeared

https://streamable.com/zh861

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private List<MataKuliah> listMatkul = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    private myAdapter myAdapter;
    private Button logoutBtn;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
    private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private NavigationView mNavigationView;
    private TextView mTextName;
    private TextView mTextNim;


    static {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }

    DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    FirebaseUser users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference mataKuliahRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("courses");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        //Navbar menu
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.navbaraction);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawabel_main);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_menu);
        View header = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        mTextName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.header_name);
        mTextNim = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.header_nim);


        //Tab Layout
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case (R.id.tugas):
                        break;
                    case (R.id.logout_menu):
                        signOut();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        userRef.child(users.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String nim = (String) dataSnapshot.child("nim").getValue().toString();

                mTextNim.setText(nim);
                mTextName.setText(name);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };


    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Beranda");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Tugas");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Pengumuman");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);


    }

}
```

ThreeFragment.java

```
   package com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment {
    View v;
    private List<DaftarPengumuman> listPengumuman = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> obj3 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ListItem> consolidatedList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private DatabaseReference userRef;
    private FirebaseUser users;
    private DatabaseReference mataKuliahRef;
    private DatabaseReference daftarPengumumanRef;

    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mataKuliahRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("courses");
        daftarPengumumanRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pengumuman");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.PengumumanRView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        adapter = new PengumumanAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), consolidatedList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        userRef.child(users.getUid()).child("courses").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                obj3.clear();
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    long datacount = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    int i = 0;
                    for(DataSnapshot dataHasil : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        final String idCourse =  dataHasil.getKey();
                        obj3.add(idCourse);
                        Log.e("anjay",obj3.toString());
                        if(datacount-1 == i){
                            queryObj3();
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }else {

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



        HashMap<String, List<DaftarPengumuman>> groupedHashMap = groupDataIntoHashMap(listPengumuman);

        for (String nama_p : groupedHashMap.keySet()) {
            PengumumanItem nameItem = new PengumumanItem();
            nameItem.setNama_matkul(nama_p);
            consolidatedList.add(nameItem);


            for (DaftarPengumuman daftarPengumuman : groupedHashMap.get(nama_p)) {
                GeneralItem generalItem = new GeneralItem();
                generalItem.setDaftarPengumuman(daftarPengumuman);//setBookingDataTabs(bookingDataTabs);
                consolidatedList.add(generalItem);
            }
        }

        return v;
    }

    public void queryObj3(){
        for(int j = 0 ; j<obj3.size() ;j++){
            mataKuliahRef.child(obj3.get(j)).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("pengumuman")) {
                            final String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
                            for (DataSnapshot idKeyPeng : dataSnapshot.child("pengumuman").getChildren()) {

                                    daftarPengumumanRef.child(idKeyPeng.getKey()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {
                                            DaftarPengumuman pengumuman = new DaftarPengumuman();
                                            pengumuman = dataSnapshot2.getValue(DaftarPengumuman.class);
                                            pengumuman.setNama_p(name);
                                            listPengumuman.add(pengumuman);

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });


                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private HashMap<String, List<DaftarPengumuman>> groupDataIntoHashMap(List<DaftarPengumuman> listOfDaftarPengumuman) {

        HashMap<String, List<DaftarPengumuman>> groupedHashMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (DaftarPengumuman daftarPengumuman : listOfDaftarPengumuman) {

            String hashMapKey = daftarPengumuman.getNama_p();

            if (groupedHashMap.containsKey(hashMapKey)) {
                // The key is already in the HashMap; add the pojo object
                // against the existing key.
                groupedHashMap.get(hashMapKey).add(daftarPengumuman);
            } else {
                // The key is not there in the HashMap; create a new key-value pair
                List<DaftarPengumuman> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(daftarPengumuman);
                groupedHashMap.put(hashMapKey, list);
            }
        }


        return groupedHashMap;
    }



}
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawabel_main"
    tools:context="com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp.MainActivity">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <include
                layout="@layout/navbar_action"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navbar_main"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navbar_header"
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`?

Comment: yes, if i add that code the app does even display threefragment at all,

Comment: I think this is asynchronous task, but I still dont have any solution.

Comment: can u help my problem @AlexMamo?

Comment: Did my answer from that post not helped you at all?

Comment: I tried to do with your answer, but its going like this now. Check video and code in ThreeFragment

Comment: Is going how? There is no new video.

Comment: hmmm.. first it took 3 times to reload, now it only took 1 times to reload. But its still problem @alex

Comment: That good if is it only once. In this case check your loops.

Comment: If i can i dont ask in this stackoverflow sir, can you help check my code?

Comment: I cannot debuf for you, you should do it and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: up.............................